# ADDING WHERE Condition in JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, database-performance

I have the following queries to filter the Active Shops in the given city and banner

```
SELECT ShopName,CityName 
FROM Shop S INNER JOIN City C ON C.CityId=S.CityId
WHERE S.Active=1 AND S.Banner like '%res%'

SELECT ShopName,CityName 
FROM Shop S INNER JOIN City C ON C.CityId=S.CityId AND S.Active=1
WHERE S.Banner like '%res%'
```

If you look both queries they give same result, But use S.Active in different places. One is IN JOIN another is in WHERE Clause.

**Which query will perform better?**

> I have 3000000 cities in City table and 40000000 shops in Shops table.
>   I have NON Clustered index created for (City,Active)

Comment: Depends, you should use SQL profiler http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx  to confirm reads and duration

Comment: I think it's better that you run both queries and tell us which is better, use profiler to monitor it.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same, but it should be in the JOIN.

In the olden days, there is no ON for JOIN, thus the joins are in the WHERE. But ANSI introduced ON in the JOIN and modern SQL engine will automatically translate the WHERE into ON.

In your scenario, what is important is that you have an index on C.CityId

Answer (score 0):

Don't stress about which will perform better. You have to understand that SQL is a DECLARATIVE not a PROCEDURAL language. In plain English, your query is going to be transformed by the query optimizer into the actual code that will run. In all liklihood it will be exactly the same.

You can look at the query plan to know for sure, but even if they are different this kind of premature optimization is a waste of time. Optimize when you know you have a problem, not before you write the query.